# Why adding Brackets around fields in where clause speed up my SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

```
select * from x
inner join lateral (
  select
    e.id,
    b_id
  from
    e
    inner join dpcat on dpcat.c_id = e.c_id 
    left join dpc on dpc.d_id = dpcat.d_id
    left join dpp on dpcat.d_id = dpp.d_id
  where
    e.c_id = x.c_id and dpc.com_id = 15 or dpp.pin_id = 1
  order by
    e.created_at desc
  FETCH FIRST
    1 ROW ONLY
) e on true
```

I can't understand why there is so much performance difference when `()` are added around this in where clause:
`(dpc.com_id = 15 or dpp.pin_id = 1)`

with brackets - 1.3 sec

without brackets - 9 sec

I am using postgresql, can anyone explain this?

Comment: The logic is different.  The two queries do different things.  Do you understand that?  No wonder they have different performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, I didn't understand the difference, that's why I posted. would have appreciated a simple explanation.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I have updated the query. That should've been `x.c_id` 
I had changed the names of tables, as this was used at my workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing different performance because you have changed the meaning of the condition. The new condition just happens to be easier for the DBMS to optimise.

In SQL, as in most programming languages, [the AND operator has higher precedence than the OR operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). That means that your original code:

```
 e.c_id = prod.c_id and dpc.com_id = 15 or dpp.pin_id = 1
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
( e.c_id = prod.c_id and dpc.com_id = 15 ) or dpp.pin_id = 1
```

That is, it will find rows which satisfy **either**

- both `e.c_id = prod.c_id` and `dpc.com_id = 15`
- **or** `dpp.pin_id = 1`, regardless of any other values

When you add parentheses, you over-ride that precedence:

```
e.c_id = prod.c_id and ( dpc.com_id = 15 or dpp.pin_id = 1 )
```

This query will find only rows which satisfy **both**:

- `e.c_id = prod.c_id`
- **and** either `dpc.com_id = 15` or `dpp.pin_id = 1`

Comment: thanks!
I forgot about precedence and yes, that changes everything.

Comment: That is why, years ago, I adapted a convention that when I have both *AND* and *OR* predicates I always parenthesis the expression. Means I do not have to remember the order of precedence (or even worse remembering incorrectly) and it clearly indicates my intent. I suggest you develop a the same convention: its worth the time to type them and a huge benefit of thinking about putting them correctly.